# Evitar que o evento seja disparado 2 vezes

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventos

Quando eu peço para abrir um modal pela primeira vez ele faz as ações corretamente, mas quando eu fecho e abro novamente o modal ele executa a função duas vezes, como evito isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
function acoesModal(){
    $('div#fixa').css('z-index', '0');
    $('.back-captcha').slideDown(500);
    $('.captcha').fadeIn(500);

    $('body').on('click','.captcha .fechar,.captcha button#retorno',function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();             
            $('div#fixa').removeAttr('style');
            $('.back-captcha').slideUp(500);
            $('.captcha').fadeOut(300);
            $('.captcha form textarea').val('');
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Há duas formas.

Utilizando a função `one`.

```
$('body').one('click', function() {
    console.log('Esta função será executada apenas uma vez');
});
```

Utilizando o `off`.

```
// removo todos os eventos do body com o namespace
// .fecharModal antes de adicioná-los novamente
$('body').off('.fecharModal').on('click.fecharModal', function() {
    console.log('Esta função será executada apenas uma vez');
});
```

A primeira forma funciona bem em casos em que o evento irá acontecer somente uma vez. Já a segunda pode ser usada em casos em que o evento pode ocorrer várias vezes.